# what is not making that my code render the collection?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I'm having a hard time trying to figre out what's wong with my code?

the thing that i'm tryng to make is get a collection o models and display them
here are my models

```
var MessageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
    id: "",
    from:"",
    titleMessage:"",
    bodyMessage:"",
    bodyMessageTrim:""
  }
});
```

My Collection

```
var MessageListCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '../js/dataDummy/populateJsonMessages.json',
  model: MessageModel
});
```

My Views

```
var MessageListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({//view for a row in the message list
  template: _.template($('#tpl-message-item-list').html()),
  render: function(eventName){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON() ));
    return this;
  },
});

var MessageListView =  Backbone.View.extend({//view por all messages listed
  className:'messages',
  render: function(){
    this.collection.each(function(model){
      var msgListAll = new MessageListItemView({model:model});
      console.log(msgListAll.el);
      this.$el.append(msgListAll.render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
});
```

Finally my Routes

```
//global model variables so i can interact with the different views
var myMessageModelAction = new MessageModel();//whole message information
var myMessageListAction = new MessageListCollection();//all the messages to be listed

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes:{
    "messages": "messagesList"
  },
  messagesList: function(){
    var myMessageList = new MessageListCollection();
    myMessageList.fetch();
    console.log(myMessageList);
    var myMessageListView = new MessageListView({collection:myMessageList});
    console.log(myMessageListView);
    myMessageListView.render();
    console.log("dame esto");
    console.log(myMessageListView.el);
    $('#rendered').html(myMessageListView.render().el);
  }
});
var appRouter = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

The File that is been called inside the collection code is just a json plain text but if it helps here it is

```
[
  {"id": "1", "from":"user1", "titleMessage":"Welcome to the Team", "bodyMessage":"Congratulations you passed the selection tests", "bodyMessageTrim": "Congratulations you passed..."},
  {"id": "2", "from":"user2", "titleMessage":"First Task", "bodyMessage":"Hello you have to make some changes in the UI", "bodyMessageTrim": "Hello you have to..."},
  {"id": "3", "from":"user2", "titleMessage":"Re:Welcome to the Team", "bodyMessage":"No problem if it's anything you might need just let me know", "bodyMessageTrim": "No problem if it's..."},
  {"id": "4", "from":"user2", "titleMessage":"Re:First Task", "bodyMessage":"Ok i am going to talk to the design team to give you all the assets", "bodyMessageTrim": "Ok i am going to talk..."},
  {"id": "5", "from":"user2", "titleMessage":"Re:Re:First Tak", "bodyMessage":"Ok that is it great work", "bodyMessageTrim": "Ok that is it..."},
  {"id": "6", "from":"user1", "titleMessage":"Meeting Tomorrow", "bodyMessage":"Hi this is just a notice that tomorrow we will have a meet with all new members", "bodyMessageTrim": "Hi this is just a..."}
]
```

The index looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <title>test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- Templates -->
      <script type="text/template" id="tpl-message-item-list" >
        <div class="messageItem">
          <div><%= from %></div>
          <div><%= titleMessage %></div>
          <div><%= bodyMessageTrim %></div>
        </div>
      </script>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container" id="rendered">
          <p>Looks like you are in the wrong place run now to a <a href="localhost/my/app/">safe place</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Libraries -->
      <script src="../js/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
      <script src="../js/lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
      <!-- Relevant Scripts -->
      <!--script src="../js/app.js"></script-->
      <script src="../js/views/appIndex.js"></script>
      <script src="../js/models/appIndex.js"></script>

      <script src="../js/collections/appIndex.js"></script>
      <script src="../js/routers/routes.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Any help is good due i'm lost and i have like 3 days playing with backbone
and all that i'm having in response is a blank screen where it should be loaded my data.

Also the collections is reached and all the data is in place just the problem is the render of it

Comment: Update: after the las answer i test directly  in the console and it works as is expected, but i think that my problem is that i'm trying to render inside a div->responseOfMessageModel.render(), is not doing it because is not in the DOM

Comment: Sorry got caught up with something, see this jsfiddle.  without css, but I basically copied all your html and js. and added "this.$el=$(this.el);" on MessageListItemView and MessageListView. http://jsfiddle.net/nickrechard/omnfbtud/14/

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Backbone View, by default, expects an el parameter when you initialize it. meaning the render will write the stuff inside that el.

if you already have some div in html page, then you can initialize backbone view like this:

```
var messageItemView=new MessageItemView({model:model,el:'#somediv'});
```

Then when render, it will write to that div.

However, it looks like you are creating a view without an element in the page, which makes sence if you do render().el, this will return the html text, and you append to main html.

while this makes sense, the backbone constructor does not know this. if you see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickrechard/omnfbtud/9/), you can see, after you initialize the MessageListItemView, the $el is null. It needs to be constructed before you do

```
this.$el.html(xxxx);
```

A hacky fix is to add a

```
render: function(eventName){
    this.$el=$(this.el);// this create the $el element;
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON() ));
    return this;
},
```

A more standard is to do it by overwrite the initialize function and do setElement();

Same thing needs to be done for MessageListView too

Comment: This answer is very accurate, but i tried the hacky way described but didn't work, and sinse i'm new to this i have a vague idea of the standard way that you mention, but can you adress me to an example of that way?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling colleciton.fetch but not waiting for it to get data before you create collectionView.

`var def = myMessageList.fetch();` return  a deferred. `def.done(function(){ /* rest  of the code here */})` should fix the problem.

Comment: i tried a different approach and after every render of the model keep stashing the render().el and after all those finish in the collection view call the this.$el to render all of them